# Get index of 2d Numpy array with 1d array

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a np array

```python
arr = np.array([[1,2,3],
                [4,5,6],
                [7,8,9],
                [1,2,3]])
```

if i have another numpy array

```python
a = np.array([1,2,3])
```

How could I find the indexes of `arr` that matches `a`
I've tried the following but it returns two arrays

```python
# desired output [0,3]
result = np.where(arr==a)

#results
#(array([0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int64),
#array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: `np.where((arr==a).all(1))[0]`

Comment: Thanks ```np.where((arr==a).all(1))[0]``` it works !